# Http Get Request Page Size Limit

Tags: c#, http, get, throttling

I'm new to web development and I'm facing an issue concerning API GET/Put Requests.

My .Net application Get's Employee data (roughly 100k) from the client through an HTTP Get Request. The client limits the 'Page' size to 50 and limits the calls per hour (3000).

The goal is to Get All users on a daily basis and filter them by Date Modified. Of course performance is a factor and I'm curious about how to trigger the GET call based on a time of day, perhaps have this function to get modified users at 2am.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Here is some sample code that I am testing.

Thank you again for the help.

```
        private List<Employee> GetMultipleUsers(SessionData sessionData, string lastModified)
    {
        var restProxy = new Proxy();
        //string lastmodified = null;
        List<Employee> employeeList = new List<Employee>();


        var v = restProxy.GetUpdatedUsers(sessionData.Token, sessionData.Secret, EnvironmentName, lastModified);
        try
        {
            MultipleUserData allUserData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MultipleUserData>(v);

            foreach (Employee e in allUserData.data.employees)
            {
                if (e.employeeMetaData.modifiedDate != DateTime.MinValue || e.employeeMetaData.modifiedDate != null)
                {
                    DateTime employeeModifiedAsDate = e.employeeMetaData.modifiedDate.GetValueOrDefault();
                    DateTime lastModifiedAsDate = DateTime.Parse(lastModified);
                    string employeeModifiedAsDateString = employeeModifiedAsDate.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                    string lastModifiedAsDateString = lastModifiedAsDate.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                    if (employeeModifiedAsDateString.Equals(lastModifiedAsDateString))
                    {
                        employeeList.Add(e);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.Write(ex.Message);
        }

        return employeeList;

    }
```